# Save and restore python interpreter state

Tags: python, c, python-embedding

Is there a way to store the state of the python interpreter embedded in a C program (not the terminal interpreter or a notebook) and restore it later resuming execution were it left off?

Other questions and answers I found about this topic evolved around saving the state of the interactive shell or a jupyter notebook or for debugging. However my goal is to freeze execution and restoring after a complete restart of the program.

A library which achieves a similar goal for the Lua Language is called Pluto, however I don't know of any similar libraries or built-in ways to achieve the same in an embedded python interpreter.

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem. Also, what do you mean by "later"?

Comment: After a restart of the embedded interpreter. Like storing the state to a file and resuming execution once the interpreter gets started again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is absolutely no way of storing the *entire* state of the CPython interpreter as it is C code, other than dumping the entire memory of the C program to a file and resuming from that. It would however mean that you couldn't restart the C program independent of the Python program running in the embedded interpreter. Of course it is not what you would want.

It could be possible in a more limited case to pickle/marshal *some* objects but not all objects are picklable - like open files etc. In general case the Python program must *actively* cooperate with freezing and restoring.